# Getting unexpected newline or end of string when using awk

Tags: bash, awk

file.txt contains

```
a,b,yes
x,y,no
```

awk -F',' '($3 == "yes")' file.txt

```
a,b,yes
```

when I use variable in awk

```
res=yes
awk -F',' "($3 == "$res")" file.txt

awk: cmd. line:1: ( == yes) 
awk: cmd. line:1:   ^ syntax error 
awk: cmd. line:2: ( == yes) 
awk: cmd. line:2:         ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F',' -v res=no '($3 == res)' file.txt
x,y,no
```

or

```
res=yes
awk -F',' "(\$3 == \"$res\")" file.txt
a,b,yes
```

Comment: Nice!  This is a very concise and helpful example for awk beginners (such as myself). +1

Comment: @Fedor Dikarev Thanks! This is helpful

Comment: @krishnan https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers